# Small spacing in the longtable near \endfoot

Tags: tables, longtable

I'm trying to use longtable (longtabu), but on all pages except the last one there is a `\cline{5-5}` that does not connected to the table.

Am I missing something? Is it possible to fix/workaround it?

Not working example of my code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{report}

\usepackage{tinos}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{polyglossia} % for russian hyphenation
\setmainlanguage{russian}
\setotherlanguage{english}

\usepackage{longtable} % another tables
\usepackage{tabu} % another tables

\newcounter{RowId}

\newcommand{\References}{}

\newcommand{\ReferencesCond}{
  \ifnum\value{RowId}=1
    \References
\fi}

\newcommand{\Row}[3]{\stepcounter{RowId}\theRowId & #1 & #2 & #3 & \ReferencesCond \\ \cline{1-4}}
\newcommand{\Lec}[2]{\Row{#1}{лк. 2}{#2}}
\newcommand{\Lab}[2]{\Row{#1}{лб. 4}{#2}}
\newcommand{\PracTwo}[2]{\Row{#1}{пр. 2}{#2}}
\newcommand{\Prac}[2]{\Row{#1}{пр. 4}{#2}}

\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\hsize=#1\hsize\raggedright}X}
\newcolumntype{S}[1]{>{\hsize=#1\hsize\centering}X}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering}X}

% document
\begin{document}
\begin{longtabu} to \linewidth {|c|l|L{.5}|S{.9}|X|}

\hline
\rowfont\bfseries
№ & Неделя &
Вид занятия\newline
Кол-во часов &
Тема и содержание занятия, форма проведения &
Наглядные пособия, оборудование и литература
\\ \hline
\endhead

\cline{5-5}
\endfoot

\Row{1}{лк}{Цель информатизации. Сбop и oбpaбoткa инфopмaции. Инфopмaциoнныe пpoцeccы.}
\Row{1}{лк}{Цель информатизации. Сбop и oбpaбoткa инфopмaции. Инфopмaциoнныe пpoцeccы.}
\Row{1}{лк}{Цель информатизации. Сбop и oбpaбoткa инфopмaции. Инфopмaциoнныe пpoцeccы.}
\Row{1}{лк}{Цель информатизации. Сбop и oбpaбoткa инфopмaции. Инфopмaциoнныe пpoцeccы.}
\Row{1}{лк}{Цель информатизации. Сбop и oбpaбoткa инфopмaции. Инфopмaциoнныe пpoцeccы.}
\Row{1}{лк}{Цель информатизации. Сбop и oбpaбoткa инфopмaции. Инфopмaциoнныe пpoцeccы.}
\Row{1}{лк}{Цель информатизации. Сбop и oбpaбoткa инфopмaции. Инфopмaциoнныe пpoцeccы.}
\Row{1}{лк}{Цель информатизации. Сбop и oбpaбoткa инфopмaции. Инфopмaциoнныe пpoцeccы.}
\Row{1}{лк}{Цель информатизации. Сбop и oбpaбoткa инфopмaции. Инфopмaциoнныe пpoцeccы.}
\end{longtabu}
\end{document}
```

[image: Pic]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

You can re-align the cline via

```
\noalign{\vskip-\arrayrulewidth}%
\cline{5-5}
\noalign{\vskip\arrayrulewidth}%
\endfoot
```

Note that you are using tabularx syntax to adjust the column widths but not making the total multiplier add up to 3 X columns, but you could use the tabu syntax. so the table is wider than the page

```
Overfull \hbox (7.16425pt too wide) in alignment at lines 58--58
```